# How to convert random XML into RSS with linq

Tags: .net-3.5, rss, linq-to-xml

I have this XML data dump

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <File>
    <Row>
        <Column Name="Job Code"></Column>
        <Column Name="# of Positions"></Column>
        <Column Name="Justification (Text Only)"/>
        <Column Name="Reason"></Column>
        <Column Name="Job Title"></Column>
        <Column Name="Purpose (Text Only)"></Column>
        <Column Name="Requirement (Text Only)"></Column>
        <Column Name="Responsibities (Text Only)"></Column>
    </Row>
  </file>
</xml>
```

As you can see the name attribute has the column type and this is about as much use as hole in the head. What I wish to do is convert this into RSS using Linq but I am struggling to work out how to create a data object from this XML

I have worked out how to walk through the columns with select case block. But I would like to LINQ to get an object that I could then pass into the RSS generation function

Comment: You might want to take a look at the XDocument class and related classes. You could pass these around. I haven't played with it yet, but I think dynamic typing could solve the problem of not being able to pass around anonymous type instances. I hope my comment and maybe a good answer will help get you pointed in the right direction. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks
I think that part of my problem is that I need to convert the Name attribute in the XML item. I am even thing of do a mad bit of regX to sort this XML out first to make my life easy

Comment: Could you show us what you want the result to look like? What RSS generation function are you using?

Comment: I an looking ot create RSS / Atom